# Capturar error en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente duda. Siempre he trabajado jQuery buscando todas las posibles caídas por error, y evitado haciendo otras funcionalidades. Sin embargo me saltó la siguiente duda. ¿Hay alguna manera de rescatar un error que se genere en jQuery por sintaxis?

Ya que muchas veces trabajo con datos dinámicos, puede que estos a veces tengan un problema que no he previsto, y saber si se puede y cómo, sería de gran ayuda.

La idea es que pueda tomar cualquier caída de jQuery, así pueda tomar medidas de estadísticas para generar parches en futuros y ademas de resolver sin que el cliente tenga que darse cuenta que hubo un error.

Comment: Puedes intentar mandar un correo electronico con la descripción del error durante la ejecucion del try catch. Ya sea a través de javascript o desde el servidor y corregir el error sin que el cliente se percate de la corrección posterior del error. Espero te sirva, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el cliente lo puedes hacer mediante `eval`, pero su uso es peligroso por que se puede utilizar para ataques como XSS. Usar `eval` en pocas palabras, hace tu sitio vulnerable.

```js
try {
  eval('console.log("b"');
} catch (e) {
  console.error('El script tiene errores');
}
```

La mejor opción en este caso sería utilizar un parser en el servidor para saber si un script es válido o no. No sé que lenguaje usas en el backend, pero por ejemplo, en Node.js se puede usar el paquete [syntax-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/syntax-error) que te evalúa un módulo (archivo JS) o un código en texto plano en busca de errores y si los encuentra te los reporta con detalle (línea donde ocurrió).

Si utilizas [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) es posible utilizar [syntax-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/syntax-error) en el navegador. Por ejemplo, si evaluamos lo siguiente:

```
var check = require("syntax-error");

// falta cierre de paréntesis
const e = check('console.log("b"');

// en caso hayan errores, devolverá un objeto
// caso contrario, nada (undefined)
if (e) {
  console.error(e.toString());
}
```

Nos mostrará el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
(anonymous file):1
console.log("b"
               ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Si trabajas con sistemas de plugins o extensiones, sin duda alguna que te será bastante útil.

Comment: En caso que trabaje con php, esta tiene que adherirse a la primera forma?

Comment: Evita la primera forma lo más que puedas, solo úsala en casos donde no haya otra alternativa. La segunda forma, usando Browserify es segura y no tiene repercusiones negativas. Browserify te permite escribir código JavaScript más moderno, importar módulos diseñados para Node.js y después, lo compila a ES5 (JavaScript del 2009), haciendo que corra en cualquier navegador.